# iPhone Motion - EXC BAD ACCESS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, exc-bad-access, motion

I'm beginning coding with the DeviceMotion class. After following Apple's documenation, i have the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myMM = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    myMM.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/30.0;
    theQ = [[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] retain];


    motionHandler = ^ (CMDeviceMotion *motionData, NSError *error) {
        if (motionData.rotationRate.z > 5.5 || motionData.rotationRate.z < -5.5) {
            NSLog(@"Rotation of Z.");  // Reference A       
        }
    };

-(IBAction)toggleClick{
    NSLog(@"toggle");

    if(myMM.gyroAvailable){

        if(myMM.deviceMotionActive){
            NSLog(@"Stopping Motion Updates..");
            [myMM stopDeviceMotionUpdates];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Starting Motion Updates..");
            [myMM startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:theQ withHandler:motionHandler];
        }

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"No motion available. Quit!");
    }
```

This code works fine, however when I want to do *any* code except an NSLog (even something as simple as incrementing an integer) in place of the 'reference A', I get an EXEC Bad Access in the console.

I've looked around, and all I've found is that it's a memory leak of sorts. Does anyone know whats going on? If not, how can I figure it out? I'm pretty inexperienced with Instruments, but if I'm pointed in the right direction I'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is an  OS-level exception meaning that you are trying to access memory that doesn't belong to you. I think this has something to do with your block being local to the scope, so once it goes out of scope, it is destroyed. You need to create a copy of it on the heap.

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659072/copying-blocks-ie-copying-them-to-instance-variables-in-objective-c/2659357#2659357) from the renowned Dave DeLong. Also, as with the normal Cocoa memory management rules, don't forget to `release` it if you've made a copy.

For example:

```
motionHandler = Block_copy(^ (CMDeviceMotion *motionData, NSError *error) {
    if (motionData.rotationRate.z > 5.5 || motionData.rotationRate.z < -5.5) {
        NSLog(@"Rotation of Z.");  // Reference A       
    }
});


// and then later:

- (void) dealloc
{
    [motionHandler release];
    //and all others.
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. I copied and pasted and worked perfectly. I would vote up, however I'm only 13 rep :(.. Thank you, and happy thanksgiving.