# iOS 5 Blocks ARC bridged cast

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

This Question references this Question:
[How to simplify callback logic with a Block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824038/how-to-simplify-callback-logic-with-a-block/4840931#comment9394551_4840931)

My header has these typedefs

```
typedef void (^StuffDoneBlock)(NSDictionary * parsedData);
typedef void (^StuffFailedBlock)(NSError * error);
```

And in init

```
stuffDoneCallback = Block_copy(done);
StuffFailedCallback = Block_copy(error);
```

In this paper its says that Block_copy is unnecessary. But then it needs a bridged cast. 
The compiler message is at follows:

```
error: cast of block pointer type 'StuffDoneBlock' (aka 'void (^)(NSDictionary *__strong)') to C pointer type 'const void *' requires a bridged cast [4]
         stuffDoneCallback = _bridge(Block_copy(done));
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Developer-4.2/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/include/Block.h:60:61: note: instantiated from:
 #define Block_copy(...) ((__typeof(__VA_ARGS__))_Block_copy((const void *)(__VA_ARGS__)))
                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the bridged cast or the block copy. Can you post how stuffDoneCallback and done are declared?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First off, why are you even using `Block_copy()`? Unless you're writing raw C, you should be calling `-copy` on the block instead, as in `[done copy]`. Secondly, ARC will copy blocks for you that need to live past their initialization scope[1], so you don't need to even call `-copy` anymore. The only "exception" is that block-typed properties still need to have the `copy` attribute.

[1]: Clarification appears to be needed here. ARC only implicitly copies blocks when *the compiler* sees that it needs to live past its initialization scope. This basically means when it's assigned to a variable that escapes the current scope (stack variable declared in a parent scope, instance variable, static, etc.). However, if it's passed as an argument to a method/function, the compiler does not do any automatic copying. Typically this isn't a problem because block-aware methods/functions that need to hold onto the block past the stack frame (`dispatch_async()`, completion blocks, etc.) will copy them for you. However, APIs that are *not* block-aware (such as `NSArray`) will not implicitly copy the block, since they expect that a simple `-retain` will do the trick. If you're passing your block to a non-block-aware API and the block needs to live past the current scope, you must use an explicit `-copy`.

Comment: I had a `NSMutableArray` of blocks that segfaulted when released with ARC. The segfault went away when I started passing copies of the blocks (obtained through `[block copy]`) to the array, so this suggests that it's actually necessary to explicitly copy the blocks under some circumstances.

Comment: Yes, APIs which don't expect to take blocks do require you to `-copy` the block if it's going to live past the current scope. That has nothing to do with ARC, since it's not reasonable to expect ARC to copy all blocks passed to other methods/functions.

Comment: In that case, you might consider an edit. The sentence "Secondly, ARC will copy blocks for you that need to live past their initialization scope, so you don't need to even call `-copy` anymore." seems to indicate the opposite.

Comment: @zneak: "live past their initialization scope" means they live in a location visible to the compiler that will exist outside the scope. In other words, if you declare a stack variable, enter a scope, assign a block to the variable, exit the scope, ARC will have copied the block for you. Similarly if you assign it to an ivar or static. However if you pass it to a method (or assign to a property), that method is then responsible for knowing whether or not the block needs to be copied. If the method is compiled with ARC and it knows it has a block, that will also probably Just Work™.

Comment: @zneak: The only real problem arises when you pass a block to a method that takes an arbitrary obj-c object and doesn't know it has just been handed a block. The normal behavior there is, if the object needs to live past the stack frame, the API will `-retain` it. However blocks need to be `-copy`'d. So in this one case only will you need to explicitly copy your block.

Comment: I know and agree with all you said. My suggestion is that you promote the precisions you made in your last comment to your answer.